# Catia V5 - Visual Basic command line for "External Storage Clean-up" feature of GSA

Tags: catia

I was wondering if there is a command line for the GSA "External Storage Clean-up" feature ("Solver Tools" toolbar).
I am looking for a Visual Basic command line compatible with Catia V5.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CATIA.StartCommand("External Storage Clean-up")

Now if you want to do more then just show the dialog, if you want to choose an option and click OK, you will need to use WINAPI methods (which should not be too difficult on that dialog).

Comment: Thank you for that command line.  
However, I wanted a solution to do the clean-up without showing the dialog box.  
I have a lot of Static Cases (about 100) computed automatically through a macro, that are memory consumming. So I wanted to integrated in that macro a way to do the clean-up automatically between each case, without intervening, because of the large number of cases to compute.

Comment: Of course you do. But it doesn't exist. That is why I suggested using WINAPI methods.
WINAPI automation of the dialogs in this case is simple and would work pretty well.

Comment: Alright, thanks, I'll investigate this suggestion.